# bash_profile on mac appears to be broken

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I was trying to work on node.js and I was changing some variables and I seem to have done some damage to the terminal which I have been unable to reverse.

Whenever I open the terminal now it says

```
Last login: Tue Apr  5 19:00:57 on ttys001
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.0': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: alias: ll: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: ls -lahG: not found
env: bash: No such file or directory
-bash: which: command not found
-bash: which: command not found
-bash: which: command not found
-bash: uname: command not found
-bash: ps: command not found
-bash: touch: command not found
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adamkatz$
```

If I try open `bash_profile` it says:

```
permission denied
```

If I use the sudo command it says:

```
sudo not found
```

And many other commands give this error.

```
env: bash: No such file or directory
```

So how do I just reset my `bash_profile` to where it starts?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you've got `export $THIS=THAT` rather than `export THIS=THAT` in there (and `$THIS` expands to nothing).  Run `/usr/bin/vi ~/.bash_profile` and correct it.

Comment: Thanks that command opened something up with the environment variables, but it is not editable

Comment: As the `$PATH` is broken you will need to use the full-path to commands like `ls` and `sudo` in order to fix the permissions.

Comment: Okay thanks, I got it to work with that first post, if you make it a comment I will green tick :)